# Cannot submit Informatica PowerCenter jobs after a Web Services Hub restart in Workload Scheduler

Tags: workload-scheduler

Following a restart of the Web Services Hub, the Plug-in for Informatica jobs launched from the command line end in FAIL state (Error state in the Dynamic Workload Console) and return the following exception in the job log:

```
AWKIPC005E Failed to run workflow.
Remote Exception
```

Answer (score 0):

To enable the correct submission of plug-in jobs, after restarting the Hub, connect to the Informatica PowerCenter Web Services Hub URL and follow these steps:

1. In the Navigator pane, expand Web Service -> Batch WebService, and
   then click Integration WebService
2. In the Operations pane, click Try-It from the toolbar
3. In the Web Service Operations avigator pane, click login.
4. Fill out the form in the right pane, pecifying the required
   information in the UserName, RepositoryName, nd Password text
   fields.
5. Click Send.
6. In the SOAP Response pane, copy the value for the SessionId tag.
7. In the Web Service Operations Navigator pane, click getWorkflowLog.
8. Paste the value copied previously in the SessionId text field and
   then enter the required information in the FolderName, WorkflowName,
   Timeout, and ServiceName text fields.
9. Click Send.

It should work.